# Python Paramiko use Variable to Execute Command

Tags: python, paramiko

i tried several solutions to add variables form read txt to be executed on exec command. but it doesn't work.

```
item = open('file.txt').read()
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('print item="%s"' % (item))
```

tried this several solutions but no results.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('print item="%s" % (item)')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('print item="%s"') % (item)
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('print item=" + (item)"')
```

Comment: Only the first is correct. The other three are wrong. - Regarding the first - What does it mean *"doesn't work"* - What does it do and what do you expect it to do differently? What is `print` command? There's no `print` command on common OSes line Linux or Windows.

Comment: Try `exec_command("echo '%s'" % (item))` for a start.